# Error in Prolog code - undefined procedure `not/2`

Tags: prolog

I have an error somewhere in the following code:

```erlang
% Induction of decision trees (program sketched on pages 466-468)
% Below, the sketched program was completed by adding some missing parts 

% Note: This program does not pay any attention to efficiency!

     induce_tree( Tree)  :-
        findall( example( Class, Obj), example( Class, Obj), Examples),
        findall( Att, attribute( Att, _ ), Attributes),
        induce_tree( Attributes, Examples, Tree).

% The form of the tree depends on the following three cases:

% (1) Tree = null if the example set is empty.
% (2) Tree = leaf( Class) if all of the examples are of the same class Class.
% (3) Tree = tree( Attribute, [ Val1 : SubTree1, Val2 : Subtree2, ...]) if examples 
%     belong to more than one class, 
%     Attribute is the root of the tree, 
%     Val1, Val2, ... are Attribute's values, and 
%     SubTree1, SubTree2, ... are the corresponding decision subtrees.

% These three cases are handled by the following three clauses:

% induce_tree( Attributes, Examples, Tree)

   induce_tree( _, [], null)  :-  !.

   induce_tree( _, [example( Class,_ ) | Examples], leaf( Class))  :-
     not(member(example(ClassX, _), Examples),           % No other example
           ClassX \== Class), !.                             % of different class

   induce_tree( Attributes, Examples, tree( Attribute, SubTrees))  :-
     choose_attribute( Attributes, Examples, Attribute), !,
     del( Attribute, Attributes, RestAtts),                  % Delete Attribute
     attribute( Attribute, Values),
     induce_trees( Attribute, Values, RestAtts, Examples, SubTrees).

   induce_tree( _, Examples, leaf( ExClasses))  :- 
     % No (useful) attribute, leaf with class distr.
     findall( Class, member( example( Class, _), Examples), ExClasses). 

% induce_trees( Att, Values, RestAtts, Examples, SubTrees):
%   induce decision SubTrees for subsets of Examples according to Values of Attribute

   induce_trees( _, [], _, _, [] ).     % No attributes, no subtrees

   induce_trees( Att, [Val1 | Vals], RestAtts, Exs, [Val1 : Tree1 | Trees]) :-
     attval_subset( Att = Val1, Exs, ExampleSubset),
     induce_tree( RestAtts, ExampleSubset, Tree1),
     induce_trees( Att, Vals, RestAtts, Exs, Trees).

% attval_subset( Attribute = Value, Examples, Subset):
%   Subset is the subset of examples in Examples that satisfy the condition 
%                                                    Attribute = Value:

   attval_subset( AttributeValue, Examples, ExampleSubset)  :-
     findall( example( Class, Obj),
              ( member( example( Class, Obj), Examples),
                satisfy( Obj, [ AttributeValue])),
              ExampleSubset).

% satisfy( Object, Description):
%   defined as in Figure 18.11. 

satisfy( Object, Conj)  :-
   not(member(Att = Val, Conj),
         member( Att = ValX, Object),
         ValX \== Val).

% choose_attribute selects the attribute that discriminates well among the classes. 
% This involves the impurity criterion. The following clause minimizes the chosen 
% impurity measure using setof. 
% setof will order the available attributes according to increasing impurity

   choose_attribute( Atts, Examples, BestAtt)  :-
     setof( Impurity/Att,
            ( member( Att, Atts), impurity1( Examples, Att, Impurity)),
            [ MinImpurity/BestAtt | _] ).

% impurity1( Examples, Attribute, Impurity):
%   implements a chosen impurity measure. 
%   Impurity is the combined impurity of the subsets of examples after 
%   dividing the list Examples according to the values of Attribute.
%   

impurity1( Exs, Att, Imp)  :-
  attribute( Att, AttVals),
  term_sum( Exs, Att, AttVals, 0, Imp).  % Weighted sum of impurities over att. values

% term_sum( Exs, Att, AttVals, PartialSum, Sum)

term_sum( _, _, [], Sum, Sum).

term_sum(Exs, Att, [Val | Vals], PartSum, Sum)  :-
  length( Exs, N),
  findall( C, (member( example(C,Desc), Exs), satisfy( Desc, [Att=Val])), ExClasses),
    % ExClasses = list of the classes (with repetitions) of all the examples with Att=Val
  length( ExClasses, NV), NV > 0, !,
  findall( P, 
           ( bagof( 1, member( Class, ExClasses), L), length( L, NVC), P is NVC/NV),
           ClassDistribution),
  gini( ClassDistribution, Gini),
  NewPartSum is PartSum + Gini*NV/N,
  term_sum( Exs, Att, Vals, NewPartSum, Sum)
  ;
  term_sum( Exs, Att, Vals, PartSum, Sum).      % Here no example satisfied Att = Val

% gini( ProbabilityList, GiniIndex)
%    GiniIndex = SUM Pi*Pj over all i, j such that i \= j
%    This is equivalent to:
%    GiniIndex = 1 - SUM Pi*Pi over all i

gini( Probs, Index)  :-
  square_sum( Probs, 0, SquareSum),
  Index is 1 - SquareSum.

square_sum( [], S, S).

square_sum( [P | Ps], PartS, S)  :-
  NewPartS is PartS + P*P,
  square_sum( Ps, NewPartS, S).
```

I get an error as follows:

```erlang
?- induce_tree(Tree).
ERROR: induce_tree/3: Undefined procedure: not/2
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         not/1
   Exception: (7) induce_tree([size, shape, holes], 
                              [example(nut, [size=small, shape=compact, holes=1]), 
                               example(screw, [size=small, shape=long, holes=none]), 
                               example(key, [size=small, shape=long, holes=1]), 
                               example(nut, [size=small, shape=compact, ... = ...]), 
                               example(key, [size=large, ... = ...|...]), 
                               example(screw, [... = ...|...]), 
                               example(nut, [...|...]), 
                               example(..., ...)|...], _G251) ?
```

Please help.

Comment: There error comes from a missing parenthesis on your `not` calls for a compound statement. You'll need to do `not((statement1, statement2))`.

Comment: Too lazy to debug I assume?

Comment: @Boris it's much easier to post here and have us debug instead. :P

Comment: @Daniel Lyons This is not true, I tryed to solve by myself doing a trace of the program execution and I noticed that, probably, the problem is in the use of the not operator, in the line: not(member(example(ClassX, _), Examples),
But I can't correct it because I have also tryed to do: not((member(example(ClassX, _), Examples)), but seems not work...anyway I don't came here before have tryed to solve by myself

Comment: Make sure you solve the `not` problem in all places that you use `not`.

Comment: This example is from Bratko, Prolog for Artificial Intelligence. In the fourth edition of 2012, there it is `..., \+ ( member( Att = Val, Conj), ...` in Fig. 20.11 as one would expect. So it seems this question refers to a much older version. In fact, older versions used `not` as a prefix operator (e.g. in the 1st edition of 1986).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```erlang
% induce_tree( Attributes, Examples, Tree)

induce_tree( _, [], null)  :-  !.

induce_tree( _, [example( Class,_ ) | Examples], leaf( Class))  :-
  not( member( example( ClassX, _), Examples),           % No other example
       ClassX \== Class ), !.                            % of different class
```

There's no `not/2` predicate, as the comments told you. And the error message surely is,

```erlang
?- induce_tree(Tree).
ERROR: induce_tree/3: Undefined procedure: not/2
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         not/1
```

So, you correct this simply by introducing more parentheses,

```erlang
% induce_tree( Attributes, Examples, Tree)

induce_tree( _, [], null)  :-  !.

induce_tree( _, [example( Class,_ ) | Examples], leaf( Class))  :-
  not( ( member( example( ClassX, _), Examples),         % No other example
         ClassX \== Class                                % of different class
       ) ), !.
```

Another, similar problem is

```erlang
satisfy( Object, Conj)  :-
   not(member(Att = Val, Conj),
         member( Att = ValX, Object),
         ValX \== Val).
```

which probably should be fixed similarly, as

```erlang
satisfy( Object, Conj)  :-
   not( ( member( Att = Val, Conj),
          member( Att = ValX, Object),
          ValX \== Val) ).
```

*edit:* new code [should use the ISO predicate `\+( ... )`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=not/1) instead of `not( ... )` which is "retained for compatibility only".

Comment: It's `\+ ( a,b )` since otherwise you need to write `\+( (a,b) )`!

Comment: yes, the extra parens are in the answer. IOW what you're saying is, the *other* fix for the OP's problem was, instead of adding the extra parens, to use `\+` *with the extra space* instead. thanks.

Comment: BTW, is the Erlang stuff really necessary? Look how odd the Error messages look now ...

Comment: Irrelevant things like "Undefined" and "However" are highlighted, what mileage do you have into this? The mode does not know ISO escape syntax in double-, single- or backquoted lists. Single quoted items are highlighted differently to atoms etc. Brief, it's more a pain than any help

Comment: for *me*, it makes it easier to read than when all is the same dark color like a solid wall. this is of course a matter of personal preference.

Comment: What would help is to color control constructs and predicates one way and real terms the other. But this requires extra contextual information like the meta_predicate declarations.

Comment: Another useful coloring would be operators, when used as operators. Take `1 + 2`  and `f(+, -)`. In the first case `+` is an operator and in the second it is just a regular atom.  Again, this requires to take into account external operator declarations.

Comment: for me, the bland one-colored wall of text is so uncomfortable, that I am willing to accept anything remotely useful in its place. at least it's got comments in gray.

Comment: ... you probably meant "motely useful", I presume

Comment: ... and `/* */` comments are not detected either.